# MySQL wont start after updating

Tags: mysql

My MySQL server (Located in /mysql) refuses to start after i updated it from 5.1 to 5.6.

Permissions:

```
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 mysql mysql 10485760 Dec 29 18:20 ibdata1
drwx---rwx. 2 mysql mysql    16384 Dec 29 15:56 lost+found
drwxr-xrwx. 2 mysql mysql     4096 Feb 23 06:48 mysql
drwx---rwx. 2 mysql mysql     4096 Feb 23 06:48 performance_schema
drwx---rwx. 2 mysql mysql     4096 Feb 23 06:48 test
```

Commands:

```
service mysqld start
MySQL Daemon failed to start.
Starting mysqld:                                           [FAILED]
```

Log:
http://pastebin.com/yWxSYeWp

my.cnf:

```
[mysqld]
datadir=/mysql
socket=/mysql/mysql.sock
user=mysql
innodb_file_per_table
innodb_flush_method=O_DIRECT
innodb_log_file_size=1G
innodb_buffer_pool_size=4G

# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0

[client]
socket=/mysql/mysql.sock

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

Using Centos 6.7

Comment: Which OS/Distro ?

Comment: Please post the log of the commands used to update MySQL. The file permissions are incorrect which is causing it to not startup properly.

Answer (score 1):

> /usr/sbin/mysqld: Can't find file: './mysql/plugin.frm' (errno: 13 - Permission denied)
>
> ...
>
> 7f498cabd720  InnoDB: Operating system error number 13 in a file operation.
> InnoDB: The error means mysqld does not have the access rights to
> InnoDB: the directory.

Amongst other things it looks like you have some sort of permissions issue. Are you starting mysql as a user with sufficient permissions ? Have you checked the permissions on the files etc in the /mysql sub directories and the permissions on the /mysql directory itself ?

> Using Centos 6.7

Another possibility is that you are using a system with SELinux enabled. The /mysql directory is non standard and as such the file security contexts may be incorrect. You may need to correct them too.

```
semanage fcontext -a -t mysqld_db_t '/mysql(/.*)?'
restorecon -rv /mysql
```

You may need to run mysql_upgrade as well as another of the error messages suggests.

Answer (score 0):

you have mysql data directory at non-standard location and your system has apparmor, ensure that `/etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld` has your data directory whitelisted. The configuration should look like:

```
/mysql/data/dir/ r, #trailing slash is mandatory
/mysql/data/dir/** rwk,
```

Apparmor daemon has to be restarted after you make any changes to config.